# CSS body and other divs not using full height

Tags: html, css

I have created a few simple websites using CSS+HTML.

In this website, I have cascaded a series of divs..

- body

  - page

    - entries

      - entry

and so i expected (1) both BODY and PAGE to enclose all the other divs, and more importantly (2) the height of BODY and PAGE to span at least the total of all the child divs.. but this doesn't happen. which has consequences in my desired behaviour.

Therefore my question is why 1 and 2 happening? CSS means Cascading Style Sheets, and so I expected the cascading to be more explicit. Most likely i'm doing something wrong..:

you can check the whole CSS and a sample HTML here:

https://jsfiddle.net/wgc8mxad/

```
body {
    padding: 0; /* don't let the browser try to be fancy */
    margin: 0;  /* don't let the browser try to be fancy */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* div width, height, border and padding included. margin not */
    word-wrap: break-word;  /* break words to avoid text going outside of div */
}

/* Default behaviour is mobile
@media (min-width: 63em) {
    .en {
        width: calc(48% - 15px);
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-right: calc(15px + 2%);
    }

    .pt {
        width: calc(48% - 15px);
        margin-left: calc(15px + 2%);
    }
}
*/

/* the viewport property is here to make sure the device (mobile) won't zoom out too present the desktop version */
/* http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972 */
@viewport{
    zoom: 1.0;
    width: extend-to-zoom; /* this is to ensure it shows correctly in both landscape and portrait mode */
}

/* Obsessive compulsive behaviour: Nobody touch the borders! */
.page {
    line-height: 1.3rem;
    margin-top: calc(1.5rem + 1%);
    margin-bottom: calc(1.5rem + 1%);
    margin-left: calc(1.5rem + 2%);
    margin-right: calc(1.5rem + 2%);
}

/* MAIN STRUCTURE */
/* This is an ID because we only use it once and specifically*/
#header {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 1.3rem;
}

#navigation {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
/* inside the header */
#title {
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}

#meta {
    float: right;
}

.entries {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

/* ENTRIES */
.entry{
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 1.3rem;
}

.en {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.pt {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    font-style: italic;
}

.entry_title{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.entry_body{
}

.entry_category{
}

.entry_footer{
    color: grey;
}
```

thanks

Comment: What isn't working for you? Fiddle provides no insight into your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the child elements are being floated, you must specify `display: inline-block;` on the parent div so that it will take those elements into account:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wgc8mxad/2/) - (Blue background added to show it takes the height of all child elements)

```
.page {
  line-height: 1.3rem;
  margin-top: calc(1.5rem + 1%);
  margin-bottom: calc(1.5rem + 1%);
  margin-left: calc(1.5rem + 2%);
  margin-right: calc(1.5rem + 2%);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**Without `display: inline-block;`:** [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wgc8mxad/3/)

---

Also, for your first question, the body is already taking the full height (yellow background is the body): [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wgc8mxad/4/)